# How to save json array into array position by position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, deserialization

I'm having a rough time trying to read the following array of json(example):

```
[
 {
  "id":"173",
  "user":"44",
  "value":"100.00"
 },
 {
  "id":"158",
  "user":"44",
  "value":"1000.00"
 }
]
```

The code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * parameters = @{@"entitty":self.entity};
NSString *url = [[defaults objectForKey:@"url_api"] stringByAppendingString:@"/blabla"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSDictionary* json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json_dict = (NSDictionary *)json_string;

//it does not fail but is copying the same information as json_dict and what I actually need is to save position by position
    NSArray * array = json_dict;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);

}];
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `NSJSONSerialization` class instead of an `NSString` to read the data?

Comment: `responseObject` should already be an `NSArray`.

Comment: BTW - You create an `NSString` object but assign it to a variable for an `NSDictionary`. Then you cast the `NSString` to an `NSDictionary`. Then you assigned the `NSDictionary` to a variable of type `NSArray`. None of those operations make any sense.

Comment: @rmaddy To receive NSArray in responseObject  AFJSONResponseSerializer should be used instead of AFHTTPResponseSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AFJSONResponseSerializer](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFJSONResponseSerializer.html) instead of AFHTTPResponseSerializer and you will receive already parsed NSArray or NSDictionary in `responseObject`.